# Programmatically create and remove a label from a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I got some code here, which creates a label just fine, but when I free the label it STILL shows on the form. Even though it's been removed and no longer 'assigned'.

Here is the code below.
It creates the label fine, but wont remove.
No exceptions, and the assigned says false.

I can reproduce this with a TRectangle as well.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
      Lab : TLabel;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Lab := TLabel.Create(Self);
  Lab.Parent := Form1;
  Lab.Text := 'Hello!';
  Lab.Position.X := 30;
  Lab.Position.Y := 40;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Lab);
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(Lab), true));
end;
```

Comment: Please show more of the code (uses clause for instance) or specify you are not using the VCL but FireMonkey which is not (yet) the mainstream framework for Delphi...

Comment: <preemptive> I know this can be inferred from the Position.X/Y properties, but still... </preemptive>

Comment: If you free a `TControl` descendant (which `TLabel` is) then it will automatically remove it from its owner AND set its parent to `nil` (check the VCL code for your version, but this is for sure the case with D2007).  You should not need to set parent to nil explicitly, so I'm not sure what is going on there.  Maybe try using `Lab.Free; Lab := nil;` instead of `FreeAndNil()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think

```
Lab.Parent:= NIL;
FreeAndNil(Lab);
```

could help.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. Any reason why? I thought freeing the object would release from the parent....

Comment: @Wizzard I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I tested under Delphi 5 and I don't need the Parent set to NIL, because the destructor sets the Parent to NIL. I can imagine that this could be a mistake of FireMonkey.

Comment: Lab.Parent := NIL generates a segmentation fault when running in Android

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, using Delphi XE (not XE2), your code works as expected (after making some small modifications, e.g. replacing Position.X with Left etc).

A few things to check/try:

- is your Parent really Form1 (since you are using Lab.Parent := Form1 instead of using self) ?
- have you tried adding Self.Repaint after free'ing Lab?

Comment: He is building a FireMonkey app in XE2. The code works as described and the solution provided by punker76 works.